# CSS DIV Alignment issues

Tags: html, css, alignment

I'm trying to align my DIV "Our source" below "Our region" and then the text DIVs on the right side. Currently "Our source" is on the right side of "our region" and the text also wrongly aligned.

Basically I'd like this:

Our Region    Blabla text

Our Source

You can see my current code here: http://jsfiddle.net/Grek/xC6wx/

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you mean something like this:

[JS Fiddle Update](http://jsfiddle.net/coltanious/t4DWe/)

Comment: Great, thanks a lot! For my info, what's the rational behind putting the div with the blabla text before the other divs, and remove the float:left ? Many thanks,

Comment: @Greg: standard floating, you only have to float one of two, etc.; http://css.maxdesign.com.au/floatutorial/